# Generate Oauth Bearer token via Java

Tags: java, oauth, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Can we refresh / regenerate OAuth tokens using the Client ID / Secret using Java? If so can someone guide me to the correct link? If not, how does a registered application refresh the expired bearer token automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do a POST request to /token with body "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxxxx" . You can use libraries like apache HttpClient to do a post request and you can find samples if you google for it

Comment: Chamila, i am getting following error. INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 403, ERROR_MESSAGE = No matching resource found in the API for the given request. Code is as below.

Comment: String clientId="xx";
String clientSecret ="yy";
String refreshToken="aaa";
String url = "http://localhost:8280/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token="+refreshToken+"&client_id="+clientId+"&client_secret="+clientSecret;
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
  //request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
System.out.println("Response Code : " 
                 + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

Comment: BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
 result.append(line);
}

Comment: Chamila, after few modifications and changing from HttpGet to HttpPost, I got now another response which is 400 and says. Response Code : 400
{"error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid","error":"invalid_grant"}

Comment: @sreedhar , would be great if you can provide the working code.

Answer (score 0):

i have three propositions to the question:

- you can kill/remove/revoke the current access token and demand another one. Check the docu of the TokenStore: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/TokenStore.html. Here A sample code:

  ```
  @Autowired
  private TokenStore tokenStore;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/revoke-token", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void revoke(HttpServletRequest request) {
      String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
      if (authHeader != null) {
          String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
          OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
          tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
      }
  }
  ```
- or you can ask a refresh token, when you demand the access token. With this refresh token, you have the possibility to demand/refresh a new access token. Here a sample code for the tokens:

  clients.inMemory()
                  .withClient("123456")
                  .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                  .scopes("scopes")
                  .resourceIds("restapi")
                  .secret("654321")
                  .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)
                  .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60)

Cheers